# Silhouette Score function in sklearn giving unexpected error

Tags: numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to run Kmeans clustering on a data. My data frame is a pandas data frame which is of following dimensions.

```
People_reduced.shape
Out[155]:
(417837, 13)
```

Now while k-means is running fine, when I try to feed the output of Kmeans cluster labels and the original data frame to silhouette_score method of sklearn , it is throwing a weird error.

Here is the code I used:

```
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=2,init='k-means++',n_init=10, max_iter=20)
kmeans.fit(People_reduced.ix[:,1:])
cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
    # The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
    # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
    # clusters
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(People_reduced.ix[:,1:].values,cluster_labels)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-b392e118f64a> in <module>()
     19     # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
     20     # clusters
---> 21 silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(People_reduced.ix[:,1:].values,cluster_labels)
     22 #silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(People_reduced.ix[:,1:], cluster_labels)
     23 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: You would get that error if `silhouette_score` was a list.  How did you define or import `silhouette_score`?

Comment: Like this: 

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit the question to include a self-contained, runnable script (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.